# $myvimrc points to a seemingly nonexistent location

Tags: vim

When I type

```
:echo $myvimrc
```

into vim, it replies

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\vim\_vimrc
```

obviously I'm on windows.  When I look there in the file explorer, I see no _vimrc.

I tried using the command prompt to list the files in the folder, but I got the same result.
if I try it with gvim, I get no response.

I have been using and making changes to my vimrc for some time, and only now have I noticed that I don't know where it is.

Where is it?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a Windows user to help you with precision, but on my Mac (or other Unix or BSD) vimrc starts with a dot, `.vimrc`, and this means the file is hidden by default from GUI and listings. I'm guessing the underscore is a similar fact for windows? Here I can list the files in the terminal with a flag `ls -a` if I want to see hidden files, or change a flag in the file for it to show in GUI.

Comment: @sidyll I thought so too, but I have my windows explorer set to show hidden files.  Dot files are hidden on windows, but underscore files are not.  "ls -a" didn't work.

Comment: Sorry @phil. Well, let's wait for a specialist then :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it was created. In the user folder. example "C:\Users\"user name" \.vimrc" or $HOME folder. 
Else   C:\Program Files(x86)\vim_vimrc